# How can I give specific number by group of identical values in a select clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this :

| Person | Dinner |
| --- | --- |
| Paul | Apple |
| Alfred | Banana |
| John | Apple |
| Jimmy | Banana |
| Johnny | Strawberry |

I want to give a specific number for each distinct value in the `Dinner` column in a select clause like this :

| Person | Dinner | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | Apple | 1 |
| Alfred | Banana | 2 |
| John | Apple | 1 |
| Jimmy | Banana | 2 |
| Johnny | Strawberry | 3 |

I tried this get the groups :

```
SELECT case when (lag(Dinner) OVER (ORDER BY id) = Dinner) or (lead(Dinner) OVER (ORDER BY Dinner) = Dinner) then 1 else 0 end,* FROM restaurant ORDER BY Dinner desc)
```

And it gives me this :

| Person | Dinner | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | Apple | 1 |
| John | Apple | 1 |
| Alfred | Banana | 0 |
| Jimmy | Banana | 0 |
| Johnny | Strawberry | 1 |

It only gives me `1` or `0` because of the `case when` case.

I'm pretty sure there's easier way to do it, but I didn't find any.

Any help ?

Comment: Your question is missing a) a column which provides the ordering you seem to think is there, and b) we need more details on the logic by which we get to the output you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `DENSE_RANK`?

```sql
SELECT Person,
       Dinner,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Dinner ASC) AS [Group]
FROM (VALUES('Paul','Apple'),
            ('Alfred','Banana'),
            ('John','Apple'),
            ('Jimmy','Banana'),
            ('Johnny','Strawberry'))V(Person, Dinner);
```